# Transform a numpy array of strings into a .txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I need to transform a numpy array:

```
array(['#fear.', 'Getting so angry.',
       'Change your mind.', ..., 'birthday boy.',
       'Living in the desert.'],
      dtype='<U234')
```

Into a .txt file, I am a bit stuck on how to do so with a numpy array, any hint? Thank you

What I want to achieve is a big .txt file where all the strings are together, like that:

```
'#fear, Getting so angry, Change your mind, birthday boy, Living in the desert'
```

The sentences does not need to be separated by a comma

Comment: yes it does, thank you @Reti43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['#fear.', 'Getting so angry.',
       'Change your mind.', ..., 'birthday boy.',
       'Living in the desert.'],
      dtype='<U234')

with open('test.txt' ,"w") as file:
    for e in arr:
        file.write(e)
```

Comment: Already answered by Reti43!